# NopCommerce OrderStatus Table?

Tags: nopcommerce

In the Admin Order page, what table does the Order Status dropdown populates?

I don't see an OrderStatus table that has values such as the default dropdown below.

```
<select name="OrderStatusId" id="OrderStatusId" data-val-number="The field Order status must be a number." data-val="true" class="valid"><option value="0" selected="selected">All</option>
<option value="10">Pending</option>
<option value="20">Processing</option>
<option value="30">Complete</option>
<option value="40">Cancelled</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In nopCommerce, OrderStatus are not stored in table. OrderStatus is defined in enum.

OrderStatus.cs

~\Libraries\Nop.Core\Domain\Orders\OrderStatus.cs